# Why is the abbreviation of Nintendo Game Cube GCN?

Tags: terminology, nintendo-gamecube

Playing Mario Kart Tour, there's something I find weird.

All Gamecube courses are marked as GCN, and I can't figure why Nintendo GameCube was abbreviated to GCN (GameCube Nintendo really doesn't sound great.)

Other consoles put the Nintendo before, like Nintendo 64 (N64) or NES or simply don't mention Nintendo like the DS, so is there any reason why the Nintendo Gamecube is abbreviated as GCN instead of something that feels more logical like NGC or GC?

Comment: I'm not sure who else but Nintendo could answer this. Seems off-topic.

Comment: I won't deny that it's riding a line, because the question is not about something in a game, but about probably a business decision around gaming. But I personally think it fits more here than on whatever the business stackexchange is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was officially branded as 'GC' in Asia, but in order to leverage the strong Nintendo brand name in Europe and North America, they tacked the 'N' on at the end:

> ...it turns out that Nintendo of Japan is referring to the GameCube in abbreviated form as "GC." So Nintendo of America (and Europe) have had to turn around and register yet another abbreviation: GCN. Nintendo of America felt it was necessary to propagate the Nintendo brand name in the Americas so it insisted on having an "N" in the abbreviation. Why couldn't the firm keep it in front of the GC? We just don't know and actually find the new abbreviation very unattractive. If you don't think it's serious about GCN, consider the fact it also applied to trademark the abbreviation GCN.
>   <sub>https://www.ign.com/articles/2000/12/13/the-name-game</sub>

And here's the official Memorandum:

[image: Memorandum]

<sup>Original Source: https://cubemedia.ign.com/media/news/image/cube/arakawamemo2.jpg</sup>

Comment: Although I don't have any sources to cite for this: it seems to me that nintendo japan was trying to transition away from the N prefix (as you see with DS or WII console abbreviations), but nintendo reps elsewhere wanted to keep the N in the name because of the strong brand. Because they didn't want the N at the beginning the only place they could put it was at the end.

Comment: But, at least to me, having the N at the end is the confusing part of the decision. The previous consoles had the N at the start to represent the console being made by Nintendo ("The Nintendo Gamecube"). "The Gamecube Nintendo" is basically broken English. I know it's the name of a console so it doesn't have to follow any grammatical rules, but it made much more sense to English speakers. I wonder if Nintendo just had trouble getting NGC trademarked?

Comment: The linked IGN article says that Nintendo actually  *did* have 'NGC' trademarked.

Comment: I googled NGC quickly and the first thing that came up was the [Numismatic Guaranty Corporation](https://www.ngccoin.com/), so maybe there was some weird legal issue with that? Honestly, I dont think a real answer exists.

Comment: @KyleRone Also, people on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/nintendo/comments/19s6w7/why_do_you_write_gcn_for_gamecube_instead_of_gc/c8r0tuy/) say NGC is trademarked to the National Geographic Channel (non-sourced). So with this said, I would agree with you on that a real answer may not exist